# How to concatonate two string variables into a result string, after using switch case method to determine new result in java?

Tags: java

So here is a link to another persons question and its my exact assignment.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834840/concatenating-switch-statements-for-playing-cards-assignment

How can I get my result string to display the valueofCard then the suitofCard in this format "value of suit"
Also, how can I shorten up the 2-10 value range within a switch case?
I am aware I have "  of  " and a couple other lines that make no sense, I just figured I am missing something big anyways.
Thanks for any help, have lots of catching up to do.

```
System.out.print("Please enter a letter/integer of a playing card (A, J, Q, K, or 2 - 10),\nfollowed by card type (D, H, S, C):");
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = kbd.nextLine();
    String valueofCard = userInput.substring(0, userInput.length() / 2);  // gives first half of string
    String suitofCard = userInput.substring(userInput.length() / 2); //give last half of string with + 1 if odd
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    switch (valueofCard) {
    case "A":
        result.append("Ace of ");
        break;
    case "J":
        result.append("Jack of ");
        break;  
    case "Q":
        result.append("Queen of ");
        break;  
    case "K":
        result.append("King of ");
        break;
    case "2":
        result.append("2 of ");
    case "3":
        result.append("3 of ");
    case "4":
        result.append("4 of ");
    case "5":
        result.append("5 of ");
    case "6":
        result.append("6 of ");
    case "7":
        result.append("7 of ");
    case "8":
        result.append("8 of ");

    case "9":
        result.append("9 of ");
    case "10":          
        result.append("10 of ");
    break;  
    }

    switch (suitofCard) {
    case "D":
        result.append("Diamonds");
        break;  
    case "H":
        result.append("Hearts");
        break;      
    case "S":
        result.append("Spades");
        break;      
    case "C":
        result.append("Clubs");
        break;
        }

    System.out.println(result.toString());

    kbd.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Your System.out.println statement is inside the "switch (suitofCard)" statement's braces.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Also, could you help me understand why the code altogether prints "AHAce of Hearts" when I input "AH" or why my case's for the number value of the card (case "2" - "10") are not returning anything?

Comment: Take a look at how "result" is being initialised,  And also compare inside the "switch (valueofCard)" what is being appended compared to A,J,Q,K :)

Comment: Thank you!!! The only problem I have left is when i input 10H or 10S, it does not read anything to the screen? I believe its because of lines                                                                                             String valueofCard = userInput.substring(0, userInput.length() / 2); 
String suitofCard = userInput.substring(userInput.length() / 2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 - You could use a Stringbuilder to do this.

```
StringBuilder cardAndSuit = new StringBuilder();

    switch (valueofCard) {
        case "A":
            cardAndSuit.append("Ace of");
    .....


     switch (suitofCard) {
        case "D":
             cardAndSuit.append("Diamonds");
            break;   
    ...

    // Print the final string
    System.out.println(cardAndSuit.toString()); // Ace of Diamonds
```

Option 2 - You could also just create a regular String and append to it.

```
String cardAndSuit = '';
cardAndSuit += "Ace of";
cardAndSuit += " Diamonds";
System.out.println(cardAndSuit); // Ace of Diamonds
```

2 is probably easier and more terse. Option 2 will actually be turned into option 1 by the compiler behind the scenes.

Comment: I have updated my code for you to review in my original question. Do you know why the very last line System.out.println(result.toString()); is unreachable code? Do you know any clean way sum up my case"2" - case "10" into one case statement that reads back one of those values (if found)